# msgstr is not a valid Python brace format string due to '�'

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

I have a Django i18n entry like:

```
#: mycode.py:2323
#, python-brace-format
msgid "Linked alias <a href=\"{alias_url}\" target=\"blank\">{alias}</a> to record <a href=\"{record_url}\" target=\"blank\">{record}</a>."
msgstr "<a href=\"{alias_url}\" target=\"blank\">エイリアス{エイリアス}</a>を会社<a href=\"{record_url}\" target=\"blank\">{会社}に</a>リンクしました。"
```

Yet when I run `django-admin compilemessages` I get the error:

```
Execution of msgfmt failed: /path/to/django.po:222: 'msgstr' is not a valid Python brace format string, unlike 'msgid'. Reason: In the directive number 1, '�' cannot start a field name.
```

Why is it complaining about the non-existent character '�' in my msgstr?